# ActionScript 3.0 Google accounts in Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I need to fetch all the installed gmail and Facebook accounts in the mobile device with ActionScript 3.0. I am using Flash Builder 4.7 and creating pure ActionScript mobile project. Can anybody help me in fetching the this list?

Comment: I think you have to create a Air Native Extension to access the AcountManager

Comment: Hi Binou. Thanks a lot for the reply. Can you please elaborate? I am not getting how to access AccountManager.
Also, how to fetch from iOS?

Comment: Native Extensions for AIR are extensions running native code with an interface accessible by your ActionScript code. Try googling about it. Here a link on how to make it: [Building a native extension for iOS and Android](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Binou. I will check that link.